# Java text file reading program with bufferedreader and FileReader. Compiling But not working

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

This program is compiling though not working. It just handling the opening file exception. Please help me.Thanks for your time.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadingFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadingFile rf = new ReadingFile();
        rf.printOnScr();
    }

    private BufferedReader openFile(String meString){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader bf = null;
        while (bf == null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter a file name");
                String fileName = sc.nextLine();

                FileReader b = new FileReader(fileName);

                bf = new BufferedReader(b);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("The file you are trying to open dose not exist.");
            }   
        }
        return bf;
    }
    private void printOnScr() {
        BufferedReader br = openFile("Please enter a file");
        try {
            while(true){
                String  line = br.readLine();
                if(line == null) break;
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("The line you are trying to access have problem/s");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add stacktrace of exception you are getting.

Comment: Why do you think that an IOException being thrown means that the file doesn't exist?  What message do you see in e?

Answer (score 1):

Very probably you're not specifying the correct path to the file when you type it. It should either be an absolute path or a relative path based at your current working directory. To see exactly what's happening, though, you'll need to look at the exception that's thrown. Either print it out with

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

or wrap it in an unchecked exception:

```
throw new IllegalStateException(e);
```

or let IOException be thrown from openFile(), through printOnScr(), and out of main()